# ImageView scaling issue in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-glide

I am using an imageview in a constraint layout and want the width of ImageView to be screen's width and height to be dynamic according to image.

My XML for layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/CardView.Light"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/newsItemBackground"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="29dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textHighEmphasis"
        android:textSize="@dimen/news_title_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/english_font"
        android:textColor="@color/textMediumEmphasis"
        android:textSize="@dimen/news_time_size"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTitle"
        tools:text="Time" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMore"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonShare"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewSeperator"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="readmore" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/share_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewSeperator"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBody"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textHighEmphasis"
        android:textSize="@dimen/news_body_size"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageNews"
        tools:text="Body" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewSeperator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/cardSeperatorLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textBody" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageNews"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTime"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/portait_man" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This image looks fine in android studio's editor however when I load it using Glide, the image's height is cropped from top and bottom.

Image from editor is

[image: Editor Image]

Image while running the app

[image: Live Image]

I am loading using the code

```
Glide.with(imageNews.getContext())
                .load(item.image_url)
                .into(imageNews);
```

Update: Jake's and Mehul's answers both gave this

[image: Updated image]

Comment: If you want to show the image to take up full width with the original aspect ratio, you need to make the layout inside scrollview

Answer (score 11):

Just set

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

and it'll work

Comment: Amazing, this worked, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Keep in mind that `centerCrop` can somewhat zoom the image a little bit.
>   If you want the `ImageView` to be flexible based on the image's resolution remove `scaleType` but this can lead to unexpected behavior.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" // Changed to wrap_content
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTime"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/portait_man" />
```

Comment: Are the constraints good? Like does the visual editor doesn't complain?

Answer (score 0):

> Try below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTitle"
            tools:text="Time" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMore"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonShare"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewSeperator"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:text="readmore" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="share_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewSeperator"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textBody"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageNews"
            tools:text="Body" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewSeperator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textBody" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNews"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTime"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_logo" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Make sure temporary i have just remove your color code and text from string.

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTitle"
            tools:text="Time" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNews"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTime"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewSeperator"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textBody"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewSeperator"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageNews"
            tools:text="Body" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewSeperator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonMore"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMore"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonShare"
            tools:text="readmore" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="share_button"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```